# Infinite while loop while when using for loop and lists

Tags: python-3.x

```
tiedosto = input("Enter the name of the file: ")
file = open(tiedosto,"r")
luku = False
while not luku:

    genre = input("> ")

    if genre == "exit":
        luku = True
    else:
        for rivi in file:
            rivi = rivi.strip()
            osat = rivi.split(";")
            if rivi.find(genre) != -1:
                print(osat[0])
```

The first time I ask for input it goes to the for loop and goes through the list and prints but the second time it asks the input it doesn't go to the for loop. Instead it asks for input until I write "exit". How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still going through the loop, but after reading the file once, the file pointer stays at the end of the file with nothing left to read -- until we reset it, with `file.seek(0)`:

```
else:
    file.seek(0) # reset the file pointer to the beginning of the file.
    for rivi in file:
```

Also, the name [`file`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) is a built-in keyword in python, which we don't want to overwrite, consider using a different variable name, like `fin`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you open a file you read line by line until the file finishes. So

`file=open(tiedosto,"r")` should be  inside `else` as well as

`file.close()`
in the end of else. This way in every loop you start reading the file from the beginning every time. So:

```
else:
    infile=open(tiedosto,"r")
    for rivi in file:
        rivi = rivi.strip()
        osat = rivi.split(";")
        if rivi.find(genre) != -1:
            print(osat[0])
    infile.close()
```

Also note that for small files it's probably faster to just keep the file's contents in memory so something like:

```
fileList = infile.readlines()
```

this will give you a list named fileList with the file's lines in it. (infile is `file` in your case)

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, reading through a file puts the cursor at the end as long as it is not reset. One possibility is to move reading the file into your `else` loop. If you do this, however, make sure that the file is closed properly

```
tiedosto = input("Enter the name of the file: ")
luku = False
while not luku:

    genre = input("> ")

    if genre == "exit":
        luku = True
    else:
        with open (tiedosto, 'r') as file:
            for rivi in file:
                rivi = rivi.strip()
                osat = rivi.split(";")
                if rivi.find(genre) != -1:
                    print(osat[0])
```

This, however is expensive if the file is large. It will potentially speed up performance if you cached off the relevant lines of the file once instead of having to load it every time.

Still, use `open`, but do the processing at the beginning:

```
tiedosto = input("Enter the name of the file: ")
collection = []
with open (tiedosto, 'r') as file:
    for rivi in file.readlines():
        collection.append((rivi, rivi.strip().split(';')))

luku = False
while not luku:

    genre = input("> ")

    if genre == "exit":
        luku = True
    else:
        for rivi, osat in collection:
            if rivi.find(genre) != -1:
                print(osat[0])
```